# What is the correct possessive adjective after "if I were you"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

For example, a student has been physically harmed by their teacher at school, and now I as a grown up want to give advice. Should I say

"If I were you, I would tell your dad about the whole thing."

OR

"If I were you, I would tell my dad about the whole thing."

The second sentence sounds weird to me since "my dad" may not even be alive as I'm a grown up, but then again I'm looking at the situation from another person's perspective. I would appreciate some clarification.

Is there a chance both of them can be considered correct?

Comment: Can you see that if you put yourself in Pat's place, then speaking to Pat's dad would be speaking to your own dad (my dad), not Askeladd's dad?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes but I've seen the first version being used in a lot of movies. I wish I could recall the names of those movies so I could make an actual example.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question because it asks about how deeply the speaker is engaging in the hypothetical world in which the speaker **is** the other person. By adopting the "if I were you" perspective, has the speaker temporarily and hypothetically become the child of the other person's father for purposes of identifying the father as "mine"? Or does the "if I were you" perspective take the speaker only as far as the judgment call about what to do, without requiring the speaker temporarily to adopt the other person's father? Nice question!

Comment: I think that this site is too much into fantasy, at the expense of clear and concise answers from many perspectives.  In my own experience, Quora comes up in the search window about ten times more often than even the mathstackexchange forum.  You have to google the most basic and driest of things to end up here and there.  This is the first question/answer that I wanted to down vote, particularly because of the high endorsement the other way.  Otherwise, I couldn't care less about the voting.

Comment: After a bit more thought, I realized that you have to have a firm grip on the various basics, before you can begin to write some good science fiction.

Comment: There is a vast body of philosophical literature that explores such matters, but there is no rule of English language that would tell you that one of these locutions is correct and the other incorrect, for the purposes of everyday conversations. You can use either, and hope that the context will make it clear what was intended. If you want to completely rule out any possibility of misunderstanding, you have to resort to some more complicated formulation, such as 'the person who would then be my dad, but would otherwise be like your real-life dad'.

Answer (score -3):

If you were the student, then you would be waiting for advice from the former you, the person asking this illogical question.

I think that the best you can do is to offer up to the student how you would have handled the situation, at the time it happened, if it had happened to you, too.  And, then, go on to say how you would handle it now.

Comment: The next thing to do here would be to ask how the helper and the student are already alike, in a sense the same person. The way this question is set up seems to try to remove the helper from student, and, then, to have the helper less responsible for telling the student less. Maybe, the helper should become more directly involved. Now I wonder how much of the the English language is to perpetuate the status quo. – Rem